# Is it possible to set a dynamically created property name from database in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

As I asked at title,

Is it possible to set a dynamically created property name from database or from an external value in C#?

If yes then how?

Comment: You might need to elaborate on that. Do you want to set a property on an existing object when the name of that property is stored in the DB?

Comment: exactly! i want to create a property on runtime but i dont want to use a static name for it. For example dynamic d = new DynamicClass(); d.FirstName... i want that FirstName part from a variable.

Comment: Really you want to store property/value pairs? I don't think you want to create dynamic properties on an object. Reed's answer is the best for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the best way to handle this is to store the value within a `Dictionary<string, object>` (or even `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, or some other class as a value).  This provides you a way to use a "dynamic property name" (the key) along with a value.

While a custom [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) will allow you to add dynamic members at runtime based on an external source, *using* those properties becomes problematic, as you don't know how to refer to them from your code.

EDIT: code example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myValues.Add("FieldName", "valueFromDatabase");
//to get value back
object val = myValues["FieldName"];
//or if not sure value exists
if (myValues.TryGetValue("FieldName", out val))
{
    //do something with val
}
```

Comment: Hi Reed, thanx for fast response. I would be pleased if u can explain that with a code sample

Comment: @user1619913 I have added a code sample, I'm not sure how long it takes for edits to show up